# $\frac{1}{\chi (G)} + \frac{\beta (G)}{|V(G)|)} \leqslant 1$

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Prove for every undirected graph $G$: $$\frac{1}{\chi (G)} + \frac{\beta (G)}{|V(G)|} \leqslant 1$$

where $\beta(G)$ is the size of the minimum vertex cover in $G$, $\chi(G)$ is the chromatic number of $G$, and $V(G)$ is the set of vertices of $G$.

I have no idea how to begin.

Any ideas?

Comment: I would suggest defining your variables $G, \chi(G), \beta(G), V(G)$ so that someone not familiar with graph theory can understand your question.

Comment: Did it, thanks @Aguila

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $V' \subseteq V$ be a minimum vertex cover of $G$; that is, each edge in $G$ is incident to at least one vertex in $V'$. It is immediate to know that $V - V'$ is a maximum independent set of $G$ and
$$
\frac{|V'|}{|V|} + \frac{|V - V'|}{|V|} = 1
$$
Note that the vertices in $G$ can be partitioned into $\chi(G)$ monochromatic classes of vertices, where each class can contain at most $|V - V'|$ vertices. Therefore,
$$
|V- V'| \cdot \chi(G) \geq |V| \Rightarrow \frac{1}{\chi(G)} \leq \frac{|V - V'|}{|V|}
$$
We conclude
$$
\frac{\beta(G)}{|V|} + \frac{1}{\chi(G)} \leq \frac{|V'|}{|V|} + \frac{|V - V'|}{|V|} = 1
$$